# how would i disable keypress ramp-up when using jquery "keypress" function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, keyboard-events, onkeypress

https://jsfiddle.net/pk2dLxuy/ is my fiddle.

```
$(document).keypress(function(keydetect) {
if(keydetect.which == 119) {
       console.log("w")
    }
if(keydetect.which == 97) {
       console.log("a")
    }
if(keydetect.which == 115) {
       console.log("s")
    }
if(keydetect.which == 100) {
       console.log("d")
    }
});
```

currently, this program, when activated, detects any of the "WASD" keys, and outputs them into the console.

but, as you start to hold one of the "WASD" keys, it starts off slowly, then it ramps up to its full speed.

how would i make it so that it is always logging to the console at full speed whilst the key is being held?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this on the Mac with code below. There is an initial delay but I am afraid that is the external key-repeat delay. Not in your control.
To circumvent this you would need a loop where key state is set by a key press and repeated. With key up cancelling. This would allow you to control it better and not be dependant on system. Does this make sense?

```js
var key;
var count = 0;

const setKey = (keyPressed) => {
  if(keyPressed != key) {
    count = 0;
    key = keyPressed;
    } else { 
    count++;
    }
    document.querySelector('#key').innerHTML = count;
};

$(document).keypress(function(keydetect) {
if(keydetect.which == 119) {
       console.log("w");
       setKey('w');
    }
if(keydetect.which == 97) {
       console.log("a");
       setKey('a');
    }
if(keydetect.which == 115) {
       console.log("s");
       setKey('s');
    }
if(keydetect.which == 100) {
       console.log("d");
       setKey('d');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="key"></div>
```